# Auth0 user management in Node.JS Express

Tags: node.js, express, auth0

I need to be able to manage users like deleting, blocking and editing a users data. I have been searching for ages now and cannot seem to find a way of doing it at all. It's not in "auth0-openid-connect" module or anything.

I have tried looking throught "auth0-openid-connect" and their API documentation and I cannot figure out how any of it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need what we call a "Management SDK" for that. You can find the full list at https://auth0.com/docs/libraries#mgmt. The Node one is available at https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0.

Comment: I am trying to use this but I cannot figure out why it wont work, I've tried several examples and none of them work.

Comment: Found it thanks :) https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md 1st one works!